# Use of undefined constant SERVICE_HTTP_PATH - assumed 'SERVICE_HTTP_PATH' in YII2

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

SERVICE_HTTP_PATH is  not getting recognised although it has been added into the XML file which contains this for web service URL.Do I need to include the XML file in the controller? If yes then how?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because I was trying to use Zend format along with YII2. Actually there is no config.inc.in file in Yii2 so we have to read the properties of the XML file using different functions and run a foreach on it so as to achieve the desired URL value.